# Passagem de valores entre Express e EJS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

Eu possui um valor `foo` que é obtido em um método assíncrono em um arquivo `db.js`.

A consulta está sendo realizada normalmente e já consigo capturar os dados da variável `foo` no meu arquivo `index.js`, mas ao tentar realizar um forEach passando `foo` para meu arquivo `index.ejs`, ele informa que `foo is not defined`

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const db = require('./db/db.js');

db.getData().then(function (result) {
    runServer(result);
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});

function runServer(foo) {
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

    // index page
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.render('pages/index', foo);
    });

    app.listen(8080);
}
```

index.ejs

```
...
<ul>
  <% foo.forEach(function(element) { %>
  <li><%= element.id %> - <%= element.nome %></li>
  <% }); %>
</ul>
...
```

db.js (não acredito que o problema seja aqui)

```
const sql = require("mssql")
const s = "SELECT ..."

const c = {
    user: "...",
    password: "...",
    server: "...",
    database: "..."
}

function execQuery(config, sqlQuery) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        const conn = new sql.ConnectionPool(config)
        const req = new sql.Request(conn)

        conn.connect(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
                return
            }
            req.query(sqlQuery, function (err, recordset) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                } else {
                    resolve(recordset.recordset)
                }
                conn.close()
            })
        })
    })
}

module.exports.getData = async function() {
    let data = await execQuery(c, s)
    return data
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tens de passar um objeto ao `render` com as chaves que queres que sejam variáveis dentro do ejs.

Ou seja, em vêz de `res.render('pages/index', foo);` deves usar assim:

```
 res.render('pages/index',{foo: foo});
```

e caso tenhas mais dados, junta outras propriedades:

```
 res.render('pages/index',{foo: foo, bar: 1234, titulo: 'minha página'});
```